# Trouble promoting subsite or moving it to a different site collection

Tags: export, import, stsadm

My company is just starting to use sharepoint for some of our contractors. And I am now tasked with the administration. (yay)

Development was done on a standalone server and they were planning on using the standalone server in production for 300+ contractors, once I was brought on board I built a farm and migrated the database over into SQL Server from SQL Express. That part worked fine.

For some reason, the portal that they built is a subsite of a subsite, of course besides for the links down, the site collection and subsite are empty. What I need to do is move that sub-subsite up to the root level. Perferably in a host-header site collection so that I can give it a specific name.

The problem I am having is I dont know enough about Sharepoint I guess. When I use: stsadm -o Export "blahserver/blah/blah/" -filename C:\blah.bak -includeusersecurity it seems to run correctly, no errors, however the blah.bak file generated is only 5k.

when I run
stsadm -o import "blahserver/" -filename C:\blah.bak -includeusersecurity
It runs, no errors, however I cant find anything that is actually created or moved.

I followed http://www.casualcoder.com/sharepoint-change-subsite-level/ exactly.

I also attempted to use export-spweb and import-spweb, I cant find the exact error from that attempt but it was in regards to the database, and was undefined.

I've been beating my head against the wall for days(If this was in anything besides sharepoint, it would be a simple drag and drop... One click). I'm to the point where a consultant might be a good idea on this one.

Any ideas how I can make it work?

Comment: Just to make sure you have it right: Did you actually create a new site at the level you want to move your exported site to? If not you want to first create a site at the level you need and then import using the new site path, basically overwriting the content with the exported site.

Comment: General Workflow:
 1. Export http://Spserver/SiteA/SubsiteA
 2. Create a new site at your new level http://SpServer/SiteB
 3. Import http://SpServer/SiteB -filename c:/SiteA.bak

Comment: I will run that workflow in a few minutes, but should that .bak be only 5k?

Comment: The 5KB size is surprising. Is your site quite bare?

Comment: not particularly, the log file generated is about 150k too, the site's DB is a couple hundred megs ATM

Comment: Can you confirmt that you are looking at the .cmp file and not the .cmp.export file. 
Anyways try the workflow and see if you have any luck.

Comment: Found it finally, I was running the command as Administrator, which diddnt have permissions in sharepoint.
Added administrator into sharepoint and I was able to do the full export. I'm still working out some issues but at least I got the import/export working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it finally, the account I was running export under did not have the correct permissions to the subsite. Added the account into sharepoint and I was able to do the full export. I'm still working out some issues but at least I got the import/export working.

Comment: Nice...Way to go!

Comment: Now I have a different problem, the sub-subsite was created using a blank template, and the site, and subsite were created using a team template, so I cant just promote, and there is a dependancy somewhere that I need to find. This is going to be complicated... I was able to bring the subsite up to the site level, so the sub-subsite is now a subsite.